# How to query a nested array in a jsonb field so that it comes out in an array using Rails

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

```rb
Book.connection.execute("SELECT books.content -> 'summaries' from books INNER JOIN authors where books.author_id = authors.id")
```

This comes out to `'[\"summary 1\", \"summary 2\",...]'` (serialized array of strings), how do I get them out as array of strings?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `Book.connection.execute` instead of `Book.joins(...).select(...)`?

Comment: @SebastianP. Let me share my thoughts on using native queries vs. a query builder. Native queries allow you to use the full power of [modern SQL](https://modern-sql.com/), query builders do not. In native queries you use a standard declarative language vs. a smudgy proprietary one that expresses declarative logic via a sequence of imperative calls. Finally you can test, profile and optimize your native query in a common database client tool while there is a certain amount of 'magic' in a query builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transform a JSONB array into a 'regular' array, use this query in your `Book.connection.execute` statement:

```sql
select array(select jsonb_array_elements_text(books.content -> 'summaries')) 
from books inner join authors on books.author_id = authors.id;
```